# Most efficient way to add multiple "attributes" to an identiy in an MySQL database

Tags: mysql, enums, boolean

I am developing a MySQL database for an Evaluation Form. I would like every Evaluator to have an attribute like Manager, Programmer, Accountant. Every Evaluator can have more than one attributes. For example he can be in the same time Manager and Programmer. 
So what is the best and most flexible way to form that in my database?

Should I add boolean columns for every attribute?

Should I add one INT column and giving a meaning to each number such as Manager = 1, Programmer = 2 ... Programer and Manager = 4...?

Should I use ENUM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have:

1. a table attribute (id, name)
2. a table evaluator (id, name, etc)
3. a table evaluator_attributes( evaluator_id, attribute_id)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by efficient.  Efficient storage-wise, or efficient in terms of performance while searching for an Evaluator who is also a Programmer (for example).

If you want to be able to use an index to search for any given attribute, you must store each attribute in a separate column.

It would be more space-efficient to use a bitfield (your second idea), but you lose the ability to search efficiently -- every search will become a table-scan.

The ENUM will not help, you probably meant the [SET data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set.html), which is a way to use bitfields while still being able to refer to the elements of the field using identifiers. This allows you to store multiple values in one column.  But this also suffers from the same limitation on searching that the manual bitfield does.